# How to handle this kind of problem in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am a new here in tornado web, when i try to open http//localhost:8888
my browser always give me an error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It's very much preferable if you post code in the post and not as image. Please provide the full error message and an example of your code containing the specific line the error is referring to. But judging on the error message itself - somewhere in the code you are initialising an instance of a class and you failed to provide a required positional argument.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectHandler` is used for **redirecting** user to a new page. If you want to display some data on the same page, use `RequestHandler`.

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler)
```